# Shading of city and country in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

when I am searching any city or state or country in google map then I want the shading of that place as shown in figure.
can any one tell me how to do it ?

[image: We are searching Mumbai, India]

Comment: No, Google does not provide that information, I'm afraid; only on their own website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this through KML layer for google maps. You can use the [JS Bin link](http://jsbin.com/yubefo/edit?html,js,output) to achieve what you want. Currently I have implemented it only for the state level but you can also do it for country. The KML I used dont provide the data for the city level.

Comment: Thanks , can you tell me how i can include pok in India  because this table shows pok in Pakistan .

Comment: can you please tell me what does 'pok' mean to you ?

Comment: POK means Pakistan occupied Kashmir , This POK is part of India but in google map It is showing in pakistan , which is wrong . And we cant show POK as a part of Pakistan so  I want to include pok in India . You can see it by searching it in google

Comment: You can edit all the data in the fusion table that we are referring for our KML by signing in on following link : [link](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419#card:id=1) . You can add another entry there for POK, but you must know all the LatLng boundaries for the POK.

Comment: I know the LatLng boundaries but I can't edit the data even on signing in on the link provided by you. Also, the Table you have used in your JS Bin has a scale of 1:10m but I need a table with a scale of 1:50m. Can you tell me any such table with scale 1:50m and having state level borders?